# mime type ('text/html') is not supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: theming

Im just trying to add Fontawesome to my new custom theme in libraries.yml but im getting: mime type ('text/html') is not supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

```
global-fontawesome:
  version: 6.2.0
  css:
    theme:
      fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css: {}
```

Comment: This seems like a web server misconfiguration but there isn’t enough information here to make any conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

Just adding attributes:

```
global-fontawesome:
  version: 6.2.0
  css:
    theme:
      fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css: {attributes:{type: "text/html"}}
```